# Terminal Colors Not Working

Tags: command-line

I am accessing an Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS server via SSH from OSX. Recently the colors stopped working. I think it happened while I was installing/troubleshooting RVM, but I am not positive.

In .bashrc I uncommeneted `force_color_prompt=yes`, and when I run `env | grep TERM` I get `TERM=xterm-color`. But still no colors.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is the output of `cat .bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi


# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac


# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
   alias dir='dir --color=auto'
   alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: Hi! Add the output of the `cat ~/.bashrc` to your question please!

Answer (score 41):

There is a sample, default `.bashrc` file located in `/etc/skel`. You could make a backup of your current `.bashrc` with:

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
```

Then copy that sample back to your home directory:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

After that, uncomment:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

in the new file and add the following back to the end (last line) of the file so that RVM still works:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

After that, execute `. ~/.bashrc` at a prompt to reload your bash profile, which should give you a colored prompt again and test RVM with the command:

```
type rvm | head -1
```

which should return the text:

```
rvm is a function
```

If this doesn't work, please let us know if you are using the standard Terminal app on Mac OS X, and what profile you are using in Terminal on your Mac.

Comment: Works for me, Xubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 10):

The colors have stopped working, most probably after you upgraded to *Lion* from *Snow Leopard*.

In Lion, for some reason, by default the terminal is declared as "**xterm-256color**" instead of "**xterm-color**" which is what Ubuntu understands.

One of the options is for you, as mentioned by previous responders, uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` in `~/.bashrc`

The other option is to redeclare in Terminal.app the terminal as xterm-color. Here's how to do that:

1. Launch Terminal.app
2. Go to menu Terminal -> Preferences (or use Cmd + ,)
3. Go to the `Settings` tab and find the theme that is set as default
4. Go to the `Advanced` tab
5. Find the drop down next to `Declare terminal as:` and set it to **xterm-color**

Here are my [Settings](http://kirichkov.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Screen-Shot-2011-07-26-at-13.36.21.png)

**UPDATE**: It seems that *Mountain Lion* removed the **xterm-color** option completely from the drop down menu. If you're doing an upgrade you will most probably keep your old configuration, but if you are doing a fresh install, you'll have to manually edit Terminal's configuration file and for that you will need a plist editor (included in *XCode* that need to be installed via the App Store). The location of Terminal's file is in **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist** in order to add the **xterm-color** option do the following:

1. Quit **Terminal.app** if it's currently running
2. Install XCode from the App Store (skip this step if you have installed it already)
3. `$ open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`
4. Navigate the plist to `Root > Window Settings`
5. locate the name of your default theme (in my case that’s Pro) expand it and find the `TerminalType` key.
6. Now just change the `TerminalType` key to **xterm-color** manually
7. save the file and launch Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and search `force_color`, the first result should highlight the `f`, just after a `#` character.

Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> for `Yes`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

You will now see color in the terminal.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to force the macOS Terminal to report TERM as the older xterm-color, you can change your .bashrc on Linux to recognize xterm-256color as a color client. This seems to be the default for newer versions of Ubuntu. To do this, change this line:

```
xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
```

to:

```
xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
```

Then run `source .bashrc` and your terminal will display in color.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative you have is to crate a `.bash_login` file if one doesn't already exist in your home directory, and put `.bashrc` inside.

Close the terminal and reopen it--your problem should be solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which I assume is because I tried to delete the default `/home/pi` user and create a new one (for security reasons), but I am not sure that I did it correctly. I ended up trying 2 things and now it works, although I am unsure which step fixed it. Here's what I did:

First I copied the `.bashrc` file to both my new user dir AND the pi user dir that I recreated.

Secondly, I did what some of the other people suggested above and tried `. ~/.bashrc` OR the longer version: `source ~/.bashrc`

Either way, I hope you can figure it out! This is my first Pi and I have just started learning Linux, and let me tell you how relieving it is to finally have color restored to the terminal!

Godspeed friend!

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! However, your answer isn't providing any new solution to this question. It's just addressing the same thing with the same method. Please [edit] to make it unique and different from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [This tutorial](http://www.developercookbook.cloud/how-to-enable-colors-on-the-username-hostname-and-working-directory-in-ubuntu-server/) found on the internet.
You can remove comment in `#force_color_prompt=yes` replacing it with `force_color_prompt=yes`.