# No terminal colors in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, colors, putty, xterm

I've tried everything from [this duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39731/terminal-colors-not-working) but I still can't get it to work. The only difference from that question is that when I run `env | grep TERM` I get `TERM=xterm` instead of `TERM=xterm-color`. I dont think it matters though, they seem to be pretty interchangeable.

What I don't understand however is that the only thing that has disappeared is the colors in the actual prompt. For example, if I run `nano` and it detects the syntax of the file, for example if it's a script, I get colors. Also when I run the `env` command mentioned earlier, the actual `TERM` text is red.

So the colors are obviously working, it's just that I don't get colored folders, executable files and so on anymore. I think it also might have occured in connection to installing Ruby/RVM. I've tried replacing `.bashrc`. (**edit** However, when creating a new user, that user has working colors)

I suppose this has a pretty simple solution but I'm just so sick of googling this now that I'd really appreciate som info on how the coloring settings works in the terminal and how this could happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You do not have problems with your terminal or terminal setting. Try this:

```
ls --color
```

It works, doesn't it?

Most likely, you have replaced your .bashrc. You can find the original .bashrc, which for example defines the alias `ls='ls --color=auto'` and also color promtpts in `/etc/skel/`.

Copy a new `.bashrc` with:

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I had an `l` alias in `.bash_profile`, so I changed that now to `alias l='ls -l --color'`. Typing `l` now gives me a colored list, but `ls` still lacks color, even though I've seen the `.bashrc` file specifically has an alias for it being colored. Ugh, thank you greatly for your answer though, I'll have to read some bash documentation.

Comment: ls (the default program) does not display colors unless you specify an option (--color=auto). If you want this to be the default behaviour, create an alias `ls='ls --color=auto'` (like most people do).

Comment: Yeah, what bugs me though is that `ls` *did* show colors initially (I think it's the default in Ubuntu Server). Nevermind, now I know how to fix it :)

Comment: The default in /etc/skel/.bashrc is to set `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, in .bashrc there is a section that states:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
# force_color_prompt=yes
```

So all that is needed is to uncomment the `force_color_promp=yes`

Comment: I would also suggest indicating to @pzkpfw to logout and login again to see the changes in action.