# How to colorize Xubuntu13.04 terminal?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, colors

On some pictures from the Internet there are colors in terminal. Even Cygwin under Windows has colors in its terminal. Here a pic from the Internet, for example:

[image]

I have installed Xubuntu and my terminal is like Windows cmd - has only two colors: background and text color. Name of user is not green. Only folders are shown in blue on `ls` command. No more any colors.

How to enable colorful terminal in Xubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 4):

Found a little info here: https://askubuntu.com/a/61763/158872

Uncomment a line:

```
# force_color_prompt=yes
```

in a file:

```
/home/user/.bashrc
```